# Parallel TRIAC's for greater heat dissipation

Tags: triac

Is it possible to parallel TRIACS to lower heat dissipation per device?

If so, what would be the best strategy to ensure balanced current sharing between devices?

The target application is to switch mains power at up to 20 amps.  The physical location would preclude heat-sinking(very small confined space) and audible clicks are not allowed.  Also, total BOM cannot be more than 3.50-4.50/load being switched.

Comment: How much do you trust the manufacturer to get the voltage drop of all the devices *exactly* equal?

Comment: I would not mind buying devices large enough to survive the initial inrush current.  The main concern is heat dissipation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no benefit for you to paralleling triacs. Using two devices crammed into the same space as a single unit (with no heat sink) will destroy itself only a bit slower than a single triac.

Triacs have a heat loss in the 1W/A (rms) region, and if you have only a few cubic inches you'll need to find a way to get the ~20W out of there while keeping the junction temperature reasonably low. This is really a non-negotiable requirement. Maybe you can put a heat pipe in there and connect it to a heat sink elsewhere. Use a smallish heat sink and a monster fan (and realize when the fan dies, so does the triac). Or liquid cooling. Or find a manufacturer (Fujitsu makes some, but not sure they cover 20A) that makes a low-audible-noise relay.

Answer (score 0):

You are seriously better off just using a larger triac than trying to parallel them.  It **IS** possible to parallel them, if you pay careful attention to wasteful series load balancing resistors, but even then, it is almost impossible to guarantee that the entire stack will turn on at the exact same time, which causes one device to take the initial current pulse alone.

Comment: I haven't seen any single device that could hold at 20A without a heatsink.

Comment: You have enough room for multiple devices, but not a heat sink?  Triacs are available in many packages, can you use a square TO3 package and wire it remotely? or an RD91 package?  Go ahead and parallel them, but provide room for low ohmage power resistors in series with each, again, eating up space, and creating heat.